# How to see what changes were made when "Automatically resolved conflict" occurs during a "Get Latest Version" in Source Control Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, tfvc

So AFAIK most/all SO posts concern themselves with 'changes/conflicts' for a check-in.

My question is about getting the latest from VSO to local workspace.

The Output of a '"Get Latest Version" in Source Control Explorer' noted...
"Conflict filename.cs - Unable to perform the get operation because you have a conflicting edit"

then...
"Automatically resolved conflict: edit: filename.cs as AutoMerge"

I cannot figure out how to view what AutoMerge did.

If I 'Compare with Workspace/Lastest version' there are no differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto Resolve Conflict usually deal with the conflicts automatically in following scenarios:

- Conflicts with any content changes (Changes made only on target or
  source)
- Conflicts caused by renaming file in the server version or
  source branch

Refer to [Specify AutoResolve Resolution Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548067(v=vs.100).aspx) for details.

When you perform "Get Latest Version" action, If you didn't do any change on your local resource since last check-in, You can compare the version before "Get Latest Version" and after "Get Latest Version" from History to see what changes were made during "Auto Resolve Conflicts". But if you did some change on your local resource and did not check-in them yet, you'll cannot see what changes does "Auto Resolve Conflicts" made since there is no history recorded for the changes you made in local.

However, you can disable "Auto Resolve Conflicts" from “Tools->Options->Source Control->Visual Studio TeamFoundation Server->Uncheck Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated" if you don't need it or select the conflict scenarios you'd like to auto merge from "Specify Conflict Type->Choose Conflicts to Resolve Window"

Comment: Thank you Eddie. I have unchecked "Uncheck Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated". However I do not have "Specify Conflict Type->Choose Conflicts to Resolve Window". I have VS2013Pro. That is probably in VS Ultimate.